# Z-index does not work (with positioning and stacking context aware)

Tags: html, image, css, iframe, z-index

I have problem with z-index. I try to make the image go under video located in iframe.

```
img
{
    position:relative;
}

iframe
{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I searched for answer and only got tips about position and stacking context which isn't problem here (If I think correctly of course). I would apprecieate some help!

EDIT 
Part of html with this img and iframe

```
<div id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">   
    <img src="images/logo/logo_biale_margins320.png" id="logo"/>    
    </div>

    <section id="page-top" class="section-style" data-background-image="images/background/page-top.jpg">
        <div class="pattern height-resize">
            <div class="container" >
                    <center><h2 class="section-name">
                        <span>
                            SHOVROOM<br/>available today!
                        </span>
                    </h2></center>
                    <h3><center>
                        Present Anything, Anywhere 
                    </center></h3>
                <br/><br/>
                <header>

                    <center>
                                        <iframe id="video"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/psraUPSYU28?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                    </center>
                </header>
```

Comment: Could you add your `html`?

Comment: Done, I added it @zgood

Comment: you html is a bit scrambled and you are using obsolete tag like center

Comment: I'm still learning @TemaniAfif thanks for feedback tho

Comment: z-index and position relative won't make any changes, you need to use absolute position

Comment: if i understand well, you want to hide the image with the iframe ? what is exactly your purpose ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif — Untrue. `z-index` applies to any element that is positioned

Comment: @Quentin what i mean is that they won't go under each other like this way with relative position

Comment: The image and the iframe are a long way apart (with lots of content between them) on the y-axis. How can you tell the iframe isn't below the img? They don't come close to overlapping.

Comment: add an wrapper with position:relative, z-index: 0; and inside it, the image, absolute and z-index -1.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, only include the code that is relevant to this question. In order to get them to overlap, I did the following.

```
position: absolute;
```

The z-index you gave seems to be working.

https://jsfiddle.net/JaredBledsoe/4v50bdwv/